# VB10, Auto-Implemented Properties and COM

Tags: vb.net, com, interop, properties

I recently finished a class that we're using to tie Access to some WCF Services.  Of course this means that the .Net classes (and all of their properties) need to be visible to COM.  Given that I'm using VB10 and the Contact class has about 20 properties I went ahead and used auto-implementing properties.

Much to my surprise, the properties were not accessible from within VBA in Access.  I tried marking the properties as ComVisible (which I didn't have to do in the past with standard properties) and it still didn't work.  After changing the auto properties to standard properties everything worked.

```
Public Property FirstName As String
```

Became

```
Public Property FirstName As String
    Get
        return _strFirstName
    End Get
    Set
        _strFirstName = value
    End Set
End Property
```

My understanding is that the two should be equivalent.  According to what I've read on MSDN, auto-implementing properties simply take care of creating the backing field and getter / setter for you and for all intents and purposes they should be the same.

Clearly they're not, so what else is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: For reference (because it took me 5 minutes to find), here's the MSDN article on auto-properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

Comment: I really hate when people do that.  I even mention in my post that I've read the article on MSDN.  That article is the reason I'm asking the question.  I'm very well aware of the fact that there should be zero difference; however, that isn't want I'm seeing in an actual real world situation.

Comment: I know that. I posted the link so *others* can refer to it. I suppose I could have edited in the link to your post. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are.  Some sample code:

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)> _
Public Class Class1
    Private prop As Boolean
    Public Property BoolProp() As Boolean
        Get
            Return prop
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            prop = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BoolProp2() As Boolean
End Class
```

With commands:

> tlbexp ClassLibrary1.dll
>   oleview ClassLibrary2.tlb

Produces this interface dump:

```
interface _Class1 : IDispatch {
    [id(00000000), propget,
      custom(54FC8F55-38DE-4703-9C4E-250351302B1C, 1)]
    HRESULT ToString([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020001)]
    HRESULT Equals(
                    [in] VARIANT obj, 
                    [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020002)]
    HRESULT GetHashCode([out, retval] long* pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020003)]
    HRESULT GetType([out, retval] _Type** pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020004), propget]
    HRESULT BoolProp([out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020004), propput]
    HRESULT BoolProp([in] VARIANT_BOOL pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020006), propget]
    HRESULT BoolProp2([out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* pRetVal);
    [id(0x60020006), propput]
    HRESULT BoolProp2([in] VARIANT_BOOL pRetVal);
};
```

It's there.  You are doing something wrong, no idea what.

Comment: Perhaps it's that I'm missing the commands you used:  "tlbexp ClassLibrary1.dll"
 and "oleview ClassLibrary2.tlb".  If I use the exact code you've posted above (copy and paste) and select "Register for COM interop" in the build settings BoolProp2 is not visible from within Access.

Comment: Unregister the assembly with Regasm.exe /u and verify that it disappeared from Access.  To make sure you didn't pick an old version.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.  I know that there should not be any difference between the two and interface dump seems to confirm that.  I'll accept this as the answer and assume I've messed up elsewhere.

Comment: I know this was posted a long time ago, but you are not the only one to experience this as seen here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/auto-implemented-property-not-exposed-to-com/299022